# Appium : Test NG with several classes

Tags: java, testng, appium

I have an issue with executing a TestNG File with several classes

I have a setup class which initiates the appiumserver and the webdriver. This method is annotated with @BeforeTest

I use pageobject model with different classes for each page and different classes for my scenario’s.

My Scenarioclasses extend the Setup Class.

When I execute the SetupClass, the methods from the first class are executed fine. But it fails when starting the methods froms the second class because the driver = null.

I can fix it for one device by making my driver static, but then I can’t execute parallell testing anymore.

I can also fix it by using @BeforeClass for my setup method, but than a new webdriver is initiated for each class. I don’t want this, since I want to execute al my tests on the same cloud device.

Someone knows how this can be fixed or any tips ?

Code Example

This is my testng file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

    <test name="Device1">

    <parameter name="device_id" value="ef13de46"/>
    <parameter name="device_name" value="samsung"/>
    <parameter name="platformVersion" value="6.0.1"/>
    <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"/>

    <classes>
        <class name="scenarios.Activation">
            <methods>
                <include name="testActivationFlow"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="scenarios.MenuBeforeActivation"/>
    </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Device2">
        <parameter name="device_id" value="ZX1G423C29"/>
        <parameter name="device_name" value="Nexus"/>
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="7.0"/>
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"/>

        <classes>
            <class name="scenarios.Activation">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testActivationFlow"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="scenarios.MenuBeforeActivation"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

This is my setup class:

```js
package setup;

public class DriverInit
{
    private String appiumServiceUrl;
    public AppiumDriver driver;

    public void startAppium()
    {
        final AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingAnyFreePort());
        service.start();
        this.appiumServiceUrl = service.getUrl().toString();
    }

    public void DriverInit(final String device_id, final String device_name, final String platformVersion, final String platformName) throws Exception
    {

        final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("app", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/app/" + "App.apk");

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", device_name);
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", device_id);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", platformName);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
       capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "<packagename>");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "<Appactivity>");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
        //capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", false);

        this.driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(this.appiumServiceUrl), capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters({"device_id", "device_name", "platformVersion", "platformName"})
    public AppiumDriver setDriver(final String device_id, final String device_name, final String platformVersion, final String platformName) throws Exception
    {
        startAppium();
        DriverInit(device_id, device_name, platformVersion, platformName);
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return this.driver;
    }

    public AppiumDriver getDriver()
    {
        return this.driver;
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        this.driver.quit();
    }


}
```

I also have a Basis class with some Basic actions

```html
public class Basis
{
    public AppiumDriver driver;

    public Basis(final AppiumDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
  ...
  
  }
```

THen I have some Page Classes following the Page Object Model

```html
public class NamePage extends Basis
{
    public NamePage(final AppiumDriver driver)
    {
        super(driver);
    }


    By nameField = By.id("edittext_name");
    By checkBox = By.id("checkbox_wallet_tac");
    By text = By.id("textview_wallet_tac");
    By buttonNext = By.id("button_next");
    By buttonCancel = By.id("button_cancel");


    public void enterName(final String strName)
    {
        this.driver.findElement(this.nameField).sendKeys(strName);
        this.driver.hideKeyboard();
    }

    public void acceptTerms()
    {
        this.driver.findElement(this.checkBox).click();
    }

    public void confirmName()
    {
        this.driver.findElement(this.buttonNext).click();
    }

}
```

THen I have my Test Classes

```html
public class Activation extends DriverInit
{

    @Test
    public void testActivationFlow() throws Exception
    {
        this.driver.resetApp();

        new Basis(this.driver).swipeLeft();

        new Basis(this.driver).swipeLeft();

        new Basis(this.driver).swipeLeft();

        new Basis(this.driver).swipeLeft();

        new WelcomePage(this.driver).startActivation();

        new NamePage(this.driver).enterName("Tester");

        new NamePage(this.driver).acceptTerms();

        new NamePage(this.driver).confirmName();

        new PinCodePage(this.driver).setPinCode();

        new PinHelper(this.driver).setPin();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

    }
}

public class MenuBeforeActivation extends DriverInit
{

    @Test
    public void testWhereCanIPay()
    {
        new MainMenuPage(this.driver).openMenu();

        new MainMenuPage(this.driver).openWherePay();

        //TODO Add assertions Webpage is opened (Title + Content)
    }

    @Test
    public void testInfoMenu()
    {
        new MainMenuPage(this.driver).openMenu();

        new MainMenuPage(this.driver).openInfo();

        new InfoPage(this.driver).openFAQ();

        //TODO Add assertions FAQ Webpage is opened

        new Basis(this.driver).back();

        new InfoPage(this.driver).openPrivacy();

        // Add assertions Privacy Text is shown

        new Basis(this.driver).back();

     

     
    }
    }
```

```
Error log : 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pages.menuPages.MainMenuPage.openMenu(MainMenuPage.java:31)
    at scenarios.MenuBeforeActivation.testWhereCanIPay(MenuBeforeActivation.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:39)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:421)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does your test classes have aftermethod or afterclass where you quit or close the driver? It could be that your tests are quitting the driver after they finish

Comment: I have a Teardown class, but these is annotated with @AfterTest. So only called after all tests. The problem seems to lie in the fact that the driver is created in the first class, and the second class cannot reach it.  Al my Test classes are extended with the setup class, so maybe that is the problem ?

Comment: I think @AfterTest and subsequent driver.quit() gets called and hence it is not available for the next test. Try commenting the call to quit and see if it works.

Comment: I am sure tearDown() method is not called after the first class. I also have the same behaviour when i don't annotate my tearDown() method. The driver is null when the first test of the second class starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you solve this using TestNG

Move the initialisation logic as part of either

- `org.testng.ITestListener` – If you would like the setup to be executed only once per `<test>` tag ( i.e., instead of using `@BeforeTest`)
- `org.testng.ISuiteListener` – If you would like the setup to be executed only once per `<suite>` tag ( i.e., instead of using `@BeforeSuite`)
- Use the `setAttribute()` method to persist the initialized data as an attribute of either the `ITestContext` (this represents a `<test>` tag ) or `ISuite` (this represents a `<suite>` tag).
- Wire in this listener into TestNG via  :

  - the `<listeners>` tag (or)
  - the `@Listeners` annotation (or)
  - Service loaders.

You can see some samples for this in [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2017/09/25/running-setup-only-once-per-testsuite-without-using-beforesuitebeforetest/) blog post of mine.

You can read more about listeners and wiring in mechanisms from [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/listen-to-what-i-have-to-say-about-testng-listeners/) blog of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Before initiating second class
- Check driver is available or not.
- Check if the first class is calling tearDown() method and cleaning up.
driver. 
- if second class is independent of first class, then initialize driver before setup() method.

To have parallel execution:
- setup xml file to pass parameter
- pass parameter from CLI.

Comment: Driver is not available when initiating second classes. Driver is not quit because i annotated my tearDown() method with @BeforeTests.

Comment: @AfterTest executes after completing all the test within the Class. Due to this when next class is called, it throws nullPointerException. Try using @BeforeClass/@AfterClass and place them under test in .xml file.  <test name="Example"> <classes> <class name="Example.TestCase1" /> <class name="Example.TestCase2" /> </classes> </test>.

Comment: Like explained I my original post I don't want to use @BeforeClass. I am sure tearDown() method is not called after the first class

Comment: It's difficult to find the reason like this. Is it possible for you to attach code snapshot and log here?

Comment: see answer below

Comment: @DDBelgium - Please edit your question and add the source code and xmls and **NOT** as an answer. It misguides other users who might end up in this question.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan So I have to replace my setDriver method with the onStart method ?

Comment: Yes. If you go through the samples in my blog it will give you the idea. You just need to adopt it into your case

Comment: Thanks Krishnan for helping me understand the issue. I agree with the implementation of TestNG Listeners.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I took some time, but I made it work for one device. I hope it will work for parallell testing also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @BeforeSuite for DriverInit, That way it will be initiated once before all tests